# error comparing enumerated types in an if statement

Tags: c++

Whenever I try to use the findPieceAt function to give me a location in the array I get an error. in the code below.

```
if (findPieceAt(newRow, newCol) != -1)
    {
        if (chessPieces[findPieceAt(newRow, newCol)].getColor == turn) //line with error
        {
            cout << "invalid attack on same color" << endl;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (chessPieces[findPieceAt(oldRow, oldCol)].captureMove(newRow, newCol) == true);
            {
                chessPieces[findPieceAt(newRow, newCol)].isCaptured;
                cout << "capture of " << chessPieces[findPieceAt(newRow, newCol)].getFullName << " is successful" << endl;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

findPieceAt function is shown below.

```
int Chess::findPieceAt(int row, int col)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < NUM_CHESS_PIECES; index++)
    {

        if (chessPieces[index].isAt(row, col) == true)
        {
            return index;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

getColor function is shown below.

```
Color ChessPiece::getColor()
{
    return color;
}
```

turn is defined below

```
void Chess::gameLoop(istream & input)
{

    Color turn = Black;  // Black will start the game
```

chessPieces array

```
private:
    static const int NUM_ROWS = 8, NUM_COLS = 8;
    static const int NUM_CHESS_PIECES = 32;
    ChessPiece chessPieces[NUM_CHESS_PIECES];
};
```

enumerated types that were used

```
enum ChessPieceType { Pawn, Rook, Knight, Bishop, Queen, King };
enum Color { White, Black };
```

Comment: And *what* error do you get?

Comment: "error C3867: 'ChessPiece::getColor': function call missing argument list; use '&ChessPiece::getColor' to create a pointer to member"       I also received another error "error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

Comment: And if you read that error message again, what do you think it could be? Especially if you look at the line where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the parentheses, as `getColor` is a function call:

```
    if (chessPieces[findPieceAt(newRow, newCol)].getColor() == turn )
```

Also, you could cache the value of `findPieceAt(newRow, newCol)` instead of calling it repeatedly in your code.

In addition, since you didn't post your entire function that has the error, you need to make sure that you return a `bool` at all exit points.  The code you posted potentially doesn't return anything if `findPieceAt(newRow, newCol)` returns -1.  Not returning a value from a function that has a return type is undefined behavior.